# Camera stays on after object is destroyed, how to turn off the camera LED in OpenCV 4.1.2.30?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pycharm, ubuntu-18.04

The LED of my camera is not turning off even when the process is finished. I've simply created a function to capture the image and then the camera must be turned off, but that's not happening.

I've even tried writing `.release()` function and `.VideoCaptureRelease()` function, but all went in vain.

The Python version I'm using is 3.6.9, on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), on PyCharm IDE 19.3.2. On top of all openCV version is **4.1.2.30**.

**The problem didn't occur in openCV 4.1.0.25!**

Anyhow, in the latest version of OpenCV, out of the blue, the LED is permanently on after using the camera. Here's the code of my small task:

```
from cv2 import *
import os


class Camera:

    def capture_pic():
        cam = VideoCapture(0)
        s, img = cam.read()
        if s:
            namedWindow("cam-test", flags=WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
            imshow("cam-test", img)
            waitKey(0)
            destroyWindow("cam-test")

            imwrite("test_pic.jpg", img)  # save image
            imshow('test_pic.jpg', img)
            waitKey(0)
            destroyAllWindows()
            cam.release()   # Used but no results

Camera.capture_pic()
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This issue was [first reported here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12301) and it seems to be caused by a problem in the *MSMF capture backend*.

Some people report that a temporary fix is to set the following **environment variable** to `0` before running the script:

```
export OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could release the cam after your if statement and just after that enter in an infinite while loop to keep the `openCV` screen opened.

Additionally, You could add a conditional with a `waitkey` to break the loop and then close the window.

```py
from cv2 import *
import os


class Camera:

    def capture_pic():
        cam = VideoCapture(0)
        s, img = cam.read()
        if s:
            namedWindow("cam-test", flags=WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
            imshow("cam-test", img)
            destroyWindow("cam-test")
            imwrite("test_pic.jpg", img)  # save image
            cv2.imshow('test_pic.jpg', img)
        cam.release()   # release the cam just after showing your image.
        while True:
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                destroyAllWindows()
                break


Camera.capture_pic()
```